# Is it possible to set a TTL for a key in a list/set?

Tags: list, redis, key, ttl

I would like to know if it is possible to set a TTL on one or more key of a list (any kind of list) or a set in Redis 3+.
What is a good alternative in case it doesn't handle it.
I have found an old question about sets but it is from 2013 so it may be irrelevant with the new releases.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like the redis doc is straightforward: http://redis.io/commands/ttl : `SET mykey "Hello" EXPIRE mykey 10TTL mykey ==> 10` (since version 1.0)

Comment: @fukanchik I am asking for a key wich is a member of a list or a set.

Comment: No, this is still the same as it was - no expiry for data structures' elements. Yet.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Thansk and i will take not of your comment on this blog post : https://quickleft.com/blog/how-to-create-and-expire-list-items-in-redis/
The trim of the list sounds great.

Comment: I think you can emulate this using compound keys: `SETNAME+"."+KEY`. This would be `EXPIRE`able. The syntax of `LRANGE` should be replaced with `KEYS "SETNAME.*"`

Comment: @fukanchik Thanks for the tip, i will also consider this.

Comment: Never. Ever. Use. `KEYS`. (in production).

Comment: @William - I remember that one, issue 41 of Redis Watch :)